# Bind selected option to variable

Tags: freemarker

I have a code like this:

```
<#assign cars = carService.findAll() >
<select name="car">
  <#foreach car in card>
    <option value="${car.id}">
      ${car.name}
    </option>
  </#foreach>
</select>
```

Is there a way to get the selected car binded to an freemarker variable (in then cars select change event, for example), so I could be able to use it to call another methods?

PS: In the example, `carService` is an EJB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't put those variables like `carSerive` there. It's the framework and/or the application code that does that. So if I understand the question well, that's where you should look around.

Comment: yeap, we have a servlet which parse these things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no way to do it the way I wanted to.

So, I had to do some JS to deal with it. It works, but it's kinda ugly.

cheers